# Trouble reading a query string in a Query String?

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

I have a URL in a query string value that is similar to this one:

```
example.com/?p1=a1&p2=a2
```

And I have a query sting on my website that takes the URL and redirects to a certain page. Like this:

```
mysite.com/?url=example.com/?p1=a1&p2=a2
```

But the query string is misinterpreted. How can I separate the query string in the value URL from the actual URL? I have tried encoding the question marks and ampersands, but the page is missing the content from the value URL.

**EDIT:**
This is how I get the URL, through a javascript:

```
 function nameps(url) {
                            url = url.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + url + "=([^&#]*)";
                            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                            if (results == null) return "";
                            else {
                                return results[1];
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: could you clarify what that second `/` is for?

Comment: Can you also give some details as to what structure you want to get out of the URL passed to your website? The example you've given look like there must be a better way of constructing the whole query.....

Comment: @Martin the second slash is part of the example URL in the query string.

Comment: So... how is your mod_rewrite (or whatever you are using to read the query) meant to interpret that? You need to URLEncode your address + query string before passing it to your page. How do you obtain the original URL?

Comment: @Martin I use Javascript to read the URL and it works just fine without encoding.

Comment: If it works just fine, then what's this question for? :-D

Comment: I think we need a little more information to be able to give you useful actual answers. Can you put in your question (edit) roughly how you intend to read the parsed URL, (as you mention, javascript, how, jQuery? etc.) as well as how your thing-that-reads-it gets hold of the URL. Then a result can be written that will actually apply to your case, because at the moment the way I would solve this problem entirely does not involve javascript, which is what you say you're using. We do only know the information you provide. Thanks :)

Comment: @Martin I know some people use asp, but it's not compatible with my system.

Comment: You **MUST** encode values. That's what the standard requires you to do. Now it's up to you whether you finally follow the standard requirement or waste your time trying to make it work just magically (or accidentally).

Comment: Can you do an output in your javascript to confirm what the input string `url` looks like before the regex work starts on it and then what it looks like after the regex has worked on the string, it appears to be an issue with the regex, but as @zerkms says, you need to properly escape the characters in the parsed URL.

Comment: @zerkms I don't encode what I don't have to.These symbols are part of the url and cant encode them: ?&=

Comment: "what I don't have to" --- you have to encode `?` and `&` and `&` if it's a part of the value

Comment: @zerkms If you have to encode it then why does Google use a big ol' question mark in the url when you search?

Comment: @Ern I just tried to search by `foo & bar` and got `q=foo%20%26%20bar` as expected. Not sure what you're referring to, sorry. Either way, the standard requires to do so. Not sure what is the point of arguing against it.

Comment: I meant the question mark that starts the query. @zerkms ?q=foo%20%26%20bar

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, I have `#` there. And, yes, I have multiple times said that you must encode it if it's a **PART OF THE VALUE**. Not sure if I need to make it flashing to be spotted.

Comment: Ern, your query has TWO question marks in it, the first tells the page on `mysite.com` that these are GET values, and the second should be escaped or encoded. Google searches never have 2 question marks in their URI. The second question mark in your URI is what @zerkms and I are referring to as needing to be properly encoded (escaped).

Answer (score 1):

how does the `url` value get passed to the javascript? That is the place you should be url-encoding the whole URL, to make

```
example.com/?p1=a1&p2=a2
```

be inputted into the javascript on your site as

```
example.com%2F%3Fp1%3Da1%26p2%3Da2
```

You will need to adjust your regex in your javascript to deal with this change in format or alternatively use a javascript url decoding function such as `decodeuri` .

[decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

such as on your site:

```
function nameps(url) {
                 url = decodeURI(url); ///new line decodes the previously encoded URL
                 url = url.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                 var regexS = "[\\?&]" + url + "=([^&#]*)";
                 var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                 var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                 if (results == null) return "";
                 else {
                      return results[1];
                      }
                 }
```

This would also involve however you pass the `url` value to the function above, would have to include the line :

```
url = encodeURI(url);
```

In order to correctly encode and format the address given.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't try to get too complicated with the query string. Instead of this:

```
mysite.com/?url=example.com/?p1=a1&p2=a2
```

I would do this:

```
mysite.com/?url=example.com&p1=a1&p2=a2
```

Then I would parse it up and rebuild the secondary url from the components.

Trying to pack a query string in a query string is asking for trouble. I wouldn't waste any time trying to get it to work that way.

Comment: "Trying to pack a query string in a query string is asking for trouble" --- it's not. It's just a single function call.